# how to create schema file of repeating sequence coming in single line in flat file

Tags: xml, xsd, repeat, flat-file

I am getting a flat file where after few position data will repeat with same sequence in same line. For example -

```
country name first name last name first name last name first name last name ......

India          A           B           C         D          E        F
```

As you can see first name and last name will repeat n number of time. As this is the flat file , all data come with position and as repeating data comes N number of time I don't know what will be total length of that line. I have manage to create xsd but I am getting error as it is going into infinite loop.

Flat file -

```
India   A    B     C     D    E   F
```

XSD -

```
<xsd:element name="Header" maxOccurs="unbounded" >
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="country" 
                   nxsd:style="fixedLength" 
                   nxsd:padStyle="head"
                   nxsd:paddedBy=" " 
                   nxsd:length="10" 
                   minOccurs="0"
                   type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="FirstName" 
                   type="xsd:string"  
                   nxsd:style="fixedLength"
                   nxsd:padStyle="head"  
                   nxsd:paddedBy=" "  
                   nxsd:length="14"  
                   minOccurs="0"/>
      <xsd:element name="LastName"  
                   type="xsd:string"  
                   nxsd:style="fixedLength" 
                   nxsd:padStyle="head"  
                   nxsd:paddedBy=" "  
                   nxsd:length="14"  
                   minOccurs="0"/>

    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

I know that I have not used terminatedBy function and because of which it is going into infinite loop but I am not going to know number of number of firstname and lastname present in file.

How to tackle this issue? Could you please help me on this?

Comment: I haven't come across this `nxsd` stuff before (nor the application of XML Schema to describing flat files). Where can I find out about this?

Comment: What is the terminatedBy function to which you refer?  This sounds as if it may be a question specific to a particular programming language or environment.

Comment: @MichaelKay That looks like a Oracle Native Schema.   https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/integration.1111/e10231/nfb.htm#TKADP2111      Microsoft BizTalk also can describe flat file formats in a XSD, but it looks quite different.